# jquery function (a,b) need explanation

Tags: jquery

I found this codesnipe and I do not understand where the a and b is given.
It works, so it may be $window. What is jquery here doing?

```
function (a, b) {
    var c = a('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
}(jQuery)
```

the html:

```
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="/Zsc0Ma07P8gupCp2k3Iu77nTOQDStpt6bToOlVt/gc=" name="csrf-token" />
```

Comment: Currently `b` is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function (a, b) {
    var c = a('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
}(jQuery)// the function call is made here
```

The first argument provided is `jQuery`, the big `jQuery` object, equivalent to the `$`. In your call, `a = jQuery` and `b = undefined` by default, as it was never provided.

```
(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a); // 5
    console.log(b); // 3
})(5, 3);
```

As @dystroy points out, this is a shorter code trick, but it's generally not used to shorten `undefined`, which can easily be obtained through any param omission. JavaScript is often minified, but minifiers cannot minify default keywords such as `document` or `window`. Performance is increased by diminishing the file size.

A far more common scenario is:

```
!function(w, d){
    w.onload = function() {
        var x = d.getElementById("whatever");
    };
}(window, document);
```

All the above should be IIFEs, or Immediately invoked. Use parentheses or any mathematical operator to force evaluation as an expression.

**Update**

Passing parameters to a function.

```
(function(a, b) { // here I am defining an anonymous function. It has no name
    console.log(a); // It takes two params, a and b.
    console.log(b);
})(5, 3); // Because of the () parentheses around it: (function(){})
// the function is evaluated as an expression. 
// because of the second group of params (5, 3) the function is called.
```

Imagine you are doing this.

```
function do(a, b) {
    // bla bla
};
do(5, 3);
```

Glue together the function definition and the function call and you get:

```
(function(a, b) {})(5, 3);
```

Comment: I added the html than you will have a token. I still do not understand why a is $window?

Comment: @alex23 thx for your explanation. I understand your mentions. Only the fact that my sample execute it with the jqwery-Object. And in this case a is not $window. Or contains the Jqwery-Object that?

Comment: it's clear now. Thats means for me that jquery is containing a=$windows right.

Answer (score 4):

It simply defines `a` as an alias of `jQuery` inside the function, and `b` as an alias of `undefined`.

Maybe you would have found this more familiar :

```
function ($, b) {
    var c = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
}(jQuery)
```

Using an alias for `undefined` is often done to have a shorter code, to minimize bandwidth.

Comment: why I do minimize bandwidth with having an undefined b ? and why jQuery gives the meta-tag back?

Comment: Yes, it's present : not passing a value for the second argument is what makes b undefined. And I absolutely not agree that your `_` convention is universal. I'd even say that there's rarely any reason to make this change, which I classify as "over-optimization".